# How do i rewrite Url and route it to different controller action in Sailsjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

As I have written in the title, i want to rewrite the URL and route it to different controller action.

Original URL : `/category1/city/locality`

Rewriten  URL : `/city/locality`

Handler      : `Controller1.action` ,

Original URL : `/category2/city/product`

Rewriten  URL : `/city/product`

Handler      : `Controller2.action`

Original URL : `/category3/city/group`

Rewriten  URL : `/city/group`

Handler      : `Controller3.action`

```
module.exports.routes = {
  // The original url and rewritten url route to the search controller
  'get /category1/:city/:locality': {'/:city/:locality', localityController.action},
  // The original url and rewritten url route to Product controller
  'get /category2/:city/:product': {'/:city/:product', productController.action},
  // The original url and rewritten url route to group controller
  'get /category3/:city/:group': {'/:city/:group', groupController.action}
 }
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: I do not get the point of doing this.

basically with the endpoints on the right you can go to that controller action, why do you need to rewrite it?

Comment: Bsc I want to rewrite the URL, I do not want categories to part of the URL

Comment: So, you don't want your end user to have to go to (for example) `/category1/city/MyLocality`, but instead just go to `/city/MyLocality` and have the system somehow magically know the difference between a locality, product and group so that it uses the correct controller to handle the request?

Comment: Yes. Please suggest if there is any way i  can achieve this.